# Hide table page in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In my code below, when i select a checkbox it displays the name of the item checked. But my problem now is, the table is paginated so when i move to the next page and return, the already checked item goes back unchecked. 
The same applies when i check a box and filter using the ajax request, when i return the already checked box will have moved to unchecked state.

How do i hide the table page to resolve this issue?

**HTML**

```
<table class="table" id="table" style="background-color:white" >
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th></th>
         <th colspan="5"></th>
         <th></th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      @foreach($items as $item) 
      <tr>
         <td><input onclick="return results(this)" data-item="{{$item->toJson()}}" type="checkbox" id="{!! $item->id !!}" name="{!! $item->name !!}" value="{!! $item->price !!}" /> </td>
         <td>{{$item->name }}</td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach       
   </tbody>
</table>
{{$items->links()}}
```

**JS**

```
function results(item){   
    var major = JSON.parse(item.dataset.item);
    if(item.checked == true)  {
     $('.panel').append(
        '<div class="container "> '+ 
        '<table style="width:100%;" class="table" id="tables">'+
        '<thead>'+'<thead>'+
        '<tbody>'+
         '<tr>'+ '<td  class="name" >'+major.name+'</td>'+] '</tr>'+
       '</tbody>'+'</table>'+'</div>')}
     } else {
     });
  }           
}
}
```

**AJAX**

```
success: function (data) {
   console.log(data);
   $("#table").slideDown('fast');
   var table = $("#table tbody");
   table.html("");
   $.each(data, function(idx, elem){
        table.append(
            "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' onclick='return results(this)' data-item='"+JSON.stringify(elem)+"' id='"+elem.id+"' name='"+elem.name+"' value='"+elem.price+"'  data-id="+elem.id+"  /></td><td >"+elem.name+"</td><tr>"
        );           
    });
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're entirely destroying the HTML with each "page": `table.html("");`  Do you want to continue to do that?  If so, you'd need to store state somewhere (such as local storage) and then examine that state when you `.append()` table rows, setting values therein as needed.  Alternatively, you could hide the rows instead of destroying them.  In this case you'd still store the state of which rows you already have so when "paging" your code would check if the rows just need to be shown before making the AJAX call to re-fetch them.

Comment: I don't know if I understood correctly or not, but it comes to my mind that you should store the selected IDs somewhere (for example cookie or browser memory or somewhere else ), and when you load the page , check the checked boxes again.

Comment: @aryaag, can you kindly show me clear cut example as i am very confused

Comment: @David, i would rather want to hide rows instead but you could assist me with a sample code to make it clearer please?

Comment: take a look at this link :
http://www.nasl-no.com/Category/Detail?Ctype=&Ids=&offset=1&count=16

it is not completed yet, but if you want something like this, I will provide a fiddle for you

Comment: @LearnLaravel: What you're asking is *pretty broad* for a Stack Overflow question.  You have a vague idea of a feature you'd like to add to your system, and are asking for assistance in implementing that feature.  If you get started on implementing the feature, where specifically do you get stuck?  Take it one step at a time.  First, stop destroying the existing HTML table rows.  See what effect that has.  Then hide the HTML table rows and see what effect that has.  Then try to un-hide a previous set of table rows, identifying which ones to unhide.  Etc., etc.

Comment: @aryaag okay kindly provide the fiddle as it my help me

Comment: ok, I will make it :)

Answer (score 2):

Saving state is possible via `"JavaScript - localStorage"` functionality.
Today browsers have capability to save information that is more "cleaner" and informative then `cookies.`

On "checkbox" element I would add event listener that would start function called `"saveState()"`. In this function I would save information about checkbox.

```
function saveState()
{
    localStorage.setItem("checkBoxStatus", "Checked");
}
```

This information is saved into browser`s storage and won't be deleted until you delete it yourself. 
To delete it you have two options:

```
`localStorage.removeItem("checkBoxStatus");` 
`localStorage.clear();`
```

Then when you re-enter that page again, while you are "constructing" view you can add small function that will set state equal to the "saved" one.

```
function resumeState()
{
    if(localStorage.getItem("checkBoxStatus") === "Checked)
         //get check box and check or uncheck
}
```

#### HOW STORED DATA CAN BE USED

It's my point of view but I prefer building my **HTML** views via `JavaScript`, as I find it more cleaner way and easier also, because today you have frequent communication with `"JavaScript/Ajax"` functions and need more responsiveness.

so I would build my entire view with JavaScript Dom
**

```
function buildView()
{
    var element = document.createElement("div"); 
        var checkBox = document.createElement("input"); 
            checkBox.settAttribute("type", "checkbox");
        //here we will check
        localStorage.getItem("checkBoxStatus") === "Checked" ? checkBox.setAttribute("checked", "true") : checkBox.setAttribute("checked", false); 
        element.appendChild(checkBox);
    document.body.appendChild(element);
}
```

**

or use `setTimeout` function and stick to "`HTML`" views:

```
<body onload='setTimeout(buildView(), 2000);>'
```

this will wait until all the `views` are constructed and start after it.
You can set correct timing depending on how much data you are loading during "`onload`" event. If it's small data you can even wait for 1 second -> `1000`

```
 function buildView()
{
     var checkBox = document.getElementById("checkBox"); 
        //here we will check
        if(localStorage.getItem("checkBoxStatus") === "Checked")
        {
            checkBox.setAttribute("checked", "true");
        }
        else 
        {
            checkBox.setAttribute("checked", false);
        }
}
```

**Remember that main here is to use localStorage functionality to save data and after that how you will use that data, totally depends on developers imagination and creativity**

Comment: so where do i start the function `resumeState()`?

Comment: I don't know your code structure but for example:

<body onload='resumeState();'>

this function starts as soon as body is loaded. And you can modify actual HTML data.

Comment: @LearnLaravel Updated

Answer (score 0):

I made a fiddle for you so that you can improve it in the way that you can use it for your purpose,here is [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Arrow891dev/7som3n1r/8/) and the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="checkbox-set">

</div>

<div id = "result">

</div>
```

Js:

```
var id = "";
for(i=1 ; i<8 ;i++){
    id="checkbox_"+i;
    $('.checkbox-set').append('<input type="checkbox" id="'+ id +'" value="Click on me"/> <label for="'+id+'">Click on me</label> <br/> ');
}
var selected = [];
        if(sessionStorage.selected) {
    // selected = sessionStorage.selected;
    var checkedIds= sessionStorage.selected.split(",");
    $.each(checkedIds,function(i){
    $("#" + checkedIds[i]).prop('checked', true);
    selected.push(checkedIds[i]);
});

    }

$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {        
        $(this).each(function(){
        selected.push($(this).attr('id'));
        //$("#result").html(selected);
        });
    }
    if(!this.checked) {
         const index = selected.indexOf($(this).attr('id'));
         var tt= selected.splice(index, 1);
             //$("#result").html(selected);
    }

    sessionStorage.selected = selected;

    $("#result").html(sessionStorage.selected);

})
```

please confirm if it is helpful